# Property map, subscribe, observable not exist

Tags: angular, rxjs5, rxjs6

Having following setup,

> Angular-4.2.4, 
>   RXJS - 5.4.2

I wanted to upgrade RXJS so I did it and now it is

> rxjs-6.2.2

I faced problems like `map, subscribe, Observable` not exist.

So installed `rxjs-compat` for backward compatibility.

> rxjs-compat-6.2.2

But still I get the same errors.

Any solution? Am I doing something wrong?

Any guidance will be pretty helpful.

***Plesae note that I don't want to upgrade Angular***

Comment: Have you deleted node_modules. try these 2 commands 1) npm cache verify --force 2) npm install.

Comment: Let me try that also.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is affected by the few breaking changes not covered by rxjs-compat try the following

To refactor TypeScript code so that it doesn't depend on rxjs-compat, you can use rxjs-tslint.

```
npm i -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p [path/to/tsconfig.json]
```

**Backwards compatibility**

Most developers with existing applications should upgrade by installing both rxjs and rxjs-compat at ^6.0.0:

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

More Info About Migration Check this:https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md
Check this also:https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/